# Disable vs2010 XNA Content Pipeline warning

Tags: c#, xna

I am building a game with XNA, and I have a custom file format for my game's levels. I want to load them and parse them myself, without using XNA's content pipeline. I have this much working, and by adding the files to the Content project I can even edit them in Visual Studio (which I also want).

The Problem: I get a warning stating "Project item 'item.lvl' was not built with the XNA Framework Content Pipeline. Set its Build Action property to Compile to build it."

I do not want XNA to Compile it, since I am doing my own parsing. How can I disable the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the file's Build Action to `None`, and then set it to `Copy if newer`.  That will cause the file to be written to the proper output directory without putting it through the Content Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be create a custom content importer as explained here: [Creating a Custom Importer and Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx). To create a simple content importer you have to inherit your class from the [`ContentImporter<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195424.aspx) (abstract class) and override the `Import()` method.

Here is a simple example from the msdn:

```
//...
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;

class PSSourceCode
{
    const string techniqueCode = "{ pass p0 { PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 main(); } }";

    public PSSourceCode(string sourceCode, string techniqueName)
    {
        this.sourceCode = sourceCode + "\ntechnique " + techniqueName + techniqueCode;
    }

    private string sourceCode;
    public string SourceCode { get { return sourceCode; } }
}

[ContentImporter(".psh", DefaultProcessor = "PSProcessor", DisplayName = "Pixel Shader Importer")]
class PSImporter : ContentImporter<PSSourceCode>
{
    public override PSSourceCode Import(string filename, 
        ContentImporterContext context)
    {
        string sourceCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
        return new PSSourceCode(sourceCode, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but I already have a parsing system for the file. Just wanted the warning about not using the pipeline to go away.